# How can I print the length of this JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to print the length of this JSON Object to the console but I keep receiving 'undefined'.

This is being JSON encoded in PHP and then returned via ajax to an anonymous function as 'msg'

```
{"1":{"item_id":"shirt_straight--small","quantity":5},"2":{"item_id":"shirt_straight--medium","quantity":"2"}}
```

Printing to console:

```
console.log(msg.length); //undefined
console.log(msg[1].item_id); //shirt_straight--small
```

I'm able to print the value of msg[1].item_id but I'm not able to get the length via msg.length

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use `Object.keys(msg).length`

Comment: your JSON is not an array. Objects don't have length attribute.

Comment: Object.keys(msg).length
That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a `length` property.  Objects do not (by default).  I think the problem is on the php end ... You should be encoding an array and sending that back instead.  Arrays are zero-indexed, so that may be the problem.  Perhaps `json_encode(array_values($msg))`.

If your keys are correct after all, give `Object.keys(msg).length` a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a duplicate of [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array)

Look at the accepted answer.

BTW, just found googling "javascript object length" ;)

**EDIT:**

It's true that objects don't have a *length* property, and you can get the length with Object.keys(foobar).length, but it won't work in IE8 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)